# Google's ML Kit bindings for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nuget-package, google-mlkit

I have used [Xamarin.Google.MLKit.FaceDetection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.MLKit.FaceDetection/) NuGet package for the `Xamarin.Android` but I couldn't find the counterpart NuGet package for the `Xamarin.iOS`.

I know this repository ([GoogleApisForiOSComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents)) exists but it seems it is not active.